# How do I configure Thunderbird to access my Gmail account?

Tags: thunderbird, gmail

I would like to check/send emails from my desktop using Thunderbird. How do I set it up to pull down my Gmail emails, and send out emails through my Gmail account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how to do it for [IMAP](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=75726) and [POP](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=12103) access.

Also, if you select to create a new account in the latest Thunderbird, it will have a "Gmail" option that automates a lot of it for you.  I think it's POP though.

Comment: +1, have used gmail + tbird for about a year now and lovin' it!

Comment: Last time I used T'bird it had that ability (circa 2008), and it was POP-only.  If you use your email on more than one system, you will **definitely** want to set it up to use IMAP.

Answer (score 1):

Lifehacker had a very nice article on doing this.

[Turn Thunderbird into the Ultimate Gmail IMAP Client](http://lifehacker.com/software/geek-to-live/turn-thunderbird-into-the-ultimate-gmail-imap-client-314574.php)

Answer (score 0):

Be **very** sure to understand how the Gmail Trash works, and how to use its SMTP server. When in doubt, see some more details at [Greyed out emails in Mail.app](https://superuser.com/questions/17188/greyed-out-emails-in-mail-app/17281#17281).